# bash test for existence of files on SFTP server

Tags: bash

The issue that I have is with the line: "**does not work**" - below.  The last line does indeed work - but I need to understand why the second to last line does not.  I need to check for file existence on the remote server.

Have a need to check for existence for files at the following location:

```
/home/remoteuser/files/
```

and when the files are processed, they are moved to:

```
/home/remoteuser/logs/archive/
```

Would like to create an alert if the files exist at - in other words, the files were not processed:

```
/home/remoteuser/logs/
```

Found the following page and seems to be what I am looking for:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/find-out-if-file-exists-with-conditional-expressions.html

Testing this and I know there are files there, but does not work:

```
ssh remoteuser@1.2.3.4 [ ! -f /home/remoteuser/logs/archive/*.* ] && echo "File does not exist in the root" >> /home/localuser/files/dirlist.txt
```

Because we know this works and does indeed list files on the local server:

```
ssh remoteuser@1.2.3.4 ls -l /home/remoteuser/logs/archive/*.* >> /home/localuser/files/dirlist.txt
```

Comment: what's your question?  You said the last code example works, right?

Comment: Look at the line "does not work" - and that is my question.

Comment: yep I saw that.  I'm asking you to clarify -- does the last line solve your problem and you are just wonering why the 2nd to last line *doesn't* work?

Comment: Yes, that is indeed the problem.  Have re-stated the question in the post.  Thanks!

Comment: FYI -- if you want to answer your own question, that should be done by adding an answer, not by editing it into the question. That way the community can upvote/downvote/&c. that answer same as any other, independently of your question.

Comment: ...but no, `[ ! -e /path/to/*.foo ]` is **not** OK. What that does is evaluate something like `[ ! -e /path/to/a.foo /path/to/b.foo /path/to/c.foo ]` -- which, if you look at it, will make it clear why you get a "too many arguments" error.

Comment: ...thing is, though, at that point your result is always false (for a failure), regardless of whether the existence test succeeds or fails. Something's a symlink to a file that doesn't exist? Doesn't matter, doesn't care, you're getting a failed result anyhow because of the syntax error!

Comment: See BashFAQ #4: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004

Comment: BTW, your question isn't using the SFTP protocol at all, but only SSH. Are you sure your title (describing it as a "SFTP server") is what you intend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Wildcards and test construct in Bash**

You cannot use the wildcards in the **[** command to test the existence of multiple files. In fact, the wildcards will be expanded and all the files will be passed to the test. Te results is that it would complain that "-f" is given too many arguments.

Try this in any non empty directory to see the output:

```
[ ! -f *.* ]
```

The only situation in which the above command does not fail is when there is only one file matching the expression, in your case a non hidden file of the form "*.*" in /home/remoteuser/logs/archive/

**Using Find**

A possible solution is to use find in combination with grep:

```
ssh name@server find /path/to/the/files -type f -name "\*.\*" 2>/dev/null | grep -q . && echo "Not Empty" || echo "Empty"
```

find search for regular files (-type f) whose names are in the form *.* (-name) and return false if nothing is found, then "grep -q ." return 1 or 0 if something is found or not.

Comment: When running the following:
`ssh remoteuser@1.2.3.4 find /home/remoteuser/logs -maxdepth 1 -type d`

I get:
`bash: find: command not found`
So..  It looks like I cannot pass find through ssh?

Comment: Sure you can but it seems that there is no find on the remote server.

Answer (score 2):

Your goal can be accomplished with only shell builtins -- and without any uses of those builtins which depend on their behavior when passed invalid syntax (as the `[ ! -e *.* ]` approach does). This removes the dependency on having an accessible, working `find` command on your remote system.

Consider:

```
rmtfunc() {
  set -- /home/remoteuser/logs/*.* # put contents of directory into $@ array
  for arg; do                      # ...for each item in that array...
    [ -f "$arg" ] && exit 0        # ...if it's a file that exists, success
  done
  exit 1                           # if nothing matched above, failure
}

# emit text that defines that function into the ssh command, then run same
if ssh remoteuser@host "$(declare -f rmtfunc); rmtfunc"; then
  echo "Found remote logfiles"
else
  echo "No remote logfiles exist"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER:**
Did find the following about the use of -e for a regular file.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-test-existence-of-file-in-bash/

Even though it says "too many arguments" it does seem to test out OK.

```
ssh remoteuser@1.2.3.4 [ ! -e /home/remoteuser/logs/archive/*.zip ] && echo "File does not exists in the root" >> /home/localuser/files/dirlist.txt || echo "File does exists in the root" >> /home/localuser/files/dirlist.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script will work simply using double parenthesis:

```
    ssh remoteuser@1.2.3.4 [[ ! -f /home/remoteuser/logs/archive/*.* ]] && echo "File does not exist in the root" >> /home/localuser/files/dirlist.txt
```

From `man bash`

> Word splitting and pathname expansion are not performed on the words between  the  [[  and  ]].

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work as [[ does not handle the *