# BASH cannot run find when using ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, find

Related to my previous question - 
[bash test for existence of files on SFTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34111012/bash-test-for-existence-of-files-on-sftp-server)

When running the following:

```
ssh remoteuser@1.2.3.4 find /home/remoteuser/logs -maxdepth 1 -type d
```

I get:

```
bash: find: command not found
```

So.. It looks like I cannot pass find through ssh?

I really need to come up with a way to check for files at:
/home/remoteuser/logs

And the logs when processed by the vendor will go into:
/home/remoteuser/logs/archive

I do need to see if the files have been processed at logs.

Comment: Obvious question first: if you SSH to the server and type 'find', you do not get this message?

Comment: find's not in the path of the remote shell. try `ssh ... /usr/bin/find` or whatever is necessary - e.g. specify the absolute path.

Comment: If you were using a better approach for your real/underlying problem, you wouldn't need `find` at all. For instance: `if ssh remoteuser@host 'set -- /home/remoteuser/logs/*; for arg; do [ -f "$arg" ] && exit 0; done; exit 1'; then echo "Found remote logfiles"; else echo "No remote logfiles"; fi`

Comment: ...the above requires no facilities at all not guaranteed to be built into a POSIX-compliant shell (`find` is required for a POSIX system, but if you're in a chroot jail that doesn't give you access to the system utilities, that does precious little good). Thus, the only case where it didn't work would be the situation where your shell was (1) not POSIX-compliant, or (2) locked in a chroot jail or otherwise unable to access `/home/remoteuser/logs`.

Comment: If you're still struggling with this, it'd be helpful to see the output of `ssh remoteuser@1.2.3.4 set` and `ssh remoteuser@1.2.3.4 ls /bin /usr/bin`

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy !!  That is very helpful!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your actual goal is to determine whether any files exist directly within a given directory, `find` is not needed for this.

Consider:

```
# this function is very careful to use only functionality built into POSIX shells.
rmtfunc() {
  set -- /home/remoteuser/logs/* # put contents of directory into $@ array
  for arg; do                    # ...for each item in that array...
    [ -f "$arg" ] && exit 0      # ...if it's a file that exists, success
  done
  exit 1                         # if nothing matched above, failure
}

# emit text that defines that function into the ssh command, then run same
if ssh remoteuser@host "$(declare -f rmtfunc); rmtfunc"; then
  echo "Found remote logfiles"
else
  echo "No remote logfiles exist"
fi
```

---

To diagnose why `find` doesn't work, check the PATH on the remote system:

```
ssh remoteuser@host 'echo "$PATH"' # important: single-quotes on the outside!
```

...and check whether a `find` executable actually exists in any directory in that PATH.